# Criar checkbox dinâmico usando o JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um formulário. Quando aperto o botão Enviar, a função verifica as informações.

Caso esteja tudo ok, eu gostaria de fazer uma tabela recheada de checkbox.

A tabela teria (flechas) linhas e (rels + ciclos) colunas. Em cada célula, gostaria de colocar o checkbox.

Infelizmente, tentei alguns posts e não obtive sucesso. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Muito obrigado!

```js
function Enviar() { 
 var flechas = document.getElementById("flechasid");
 var rels = document.getElementById("relsid");  
 var ciclos = document.getElementById("ciclosid"); 
 if (flechas.value > 0 && flechas.value < 30 && ciclos.value > 0 && ciclos.value < 10 && rels.value > 0 && rels.value < 20) { 
  alert('Os seus dados foram encaminhados com sucesso!');
        } else {
  alert('Informações inválidas!');
 };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Aprenda a criar PHIAs">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
</head>

<body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<form name="Untitled-2">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>
   Número de relações do tipo 3  
  </legend>
   <table cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
       <td>
         <label for="rels">
          Relações
         </label>
       </td>
       <td align="left">
         <input type="text" name="rels" id="relsid" required="required" placeholder=0>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>
   Número de flechas nessas relações  
  </legend>
   <table cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
       <td>
         <label for="flechas">
          Flechas
         </label>
       </td>
       <td align="left">
         <input type="text" name="flechas" id="flechasid" required="required" placeholder=0>
     </td>
    </tr>
    
   </table>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>
   Número de ciclos elementares  
  </legend>
   <table cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
       <td>
         <label for="ciclos">
          Ciclos
         </label>
       </td>
       <td align="left">
         <input type="text" name="ciclos" id="ciclosid" required="required" placeholder=0>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </fieldset>

 <input type="button" onclick="Enviar();" value="Enviar">
 <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
</form>

<div id="test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Como criar uma tabela em JavaScript?

#### Dados estruturados

Idealmente deves ter algum objeto ou array com a estrutura e dados da tabela.

Por exemplo se cada linha fôr o ID de uma relação e cada célula tiver um nome poderias ter algo assim:

```
// exemplo A
var data = [{
    idLinha1: [{
        isRelacao: 'r1'
    }, {
        idFlecha: 'f1'
    }, {
        idCiclo: 'c1'
    }],
    idLinha2: [{
        isRelacao: 'r2'
    }, {
        idFlecha: 'f2'
    }, {
        idCiclo: 'c2'
    }],
    // etc...
```

Se não fôr necessário IDs para cada céluna podes fazer algo mais simples assim:

```
// exemplo B
var data = {
    celulas: ['relacao', 'flecha', 'ciclo'],
    idLinhas: ['linha1', 'linha2', 'linha3', ...etc ]
}
```

**Duas coisas importantes a ter em conta:**

- pensa como queres usar os dados depois, criar o HTML certo facilita muito quando fôr altura de retirar informação
- Arrays respeitam ordem, objetos não. Se fôr importante a ordem das linhas iteram uma array e não chaves de objetos.

#### Como criar os elementos

cada elemento deve ser criado com `document.createElement()` onde passas o nome da tag para o método nativo.

Um exemplo para o exemplo B seria

```
var table = document.createElement('table');

// cabeçalho da table
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var th = document.createElement('th');
tr.appendChild(th); // vazia
data.celulas.forEach(function (celula) { // Nota "a)"
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = celula;
    tr.appendChild(th);
});
table.appendChild(tr);

// corpo
data.idLinhas.forEach(function (id) {
    // criar nova linha
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.dataset.id = id;
    // primeira célula com nome da linha
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = id;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    // percorrer array de TDs
    data.celulas.forEach(function (celula) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'checkbox';
        input.name = celula + []; // * - Nota "b)"
        td.appendChild(input);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
// adicionar tabela ao documento
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oyt94rek/**

Notas:

a) O que faz `data.celulas.forEach(function (celula) {});`?

Esta linha é para criar o conteúdo do titulo das colunas. `data.celulas` é uma array que tem os nomes que devem estar no topo de cada coluna. [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) é um método nativo de array para percorrer o array elemento a elemento. Assim passando-lhe uma função ele vai disponibilizar cada elemento, na variável `celula`.

b) - usei `[]` pois caso envies para o servidor ele vai tratar os inputs com o mesmo nome como uma array.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio . 
Eu sou novo na programação mas consegui implementar a sua resposta para a minha situação. Não sei se vou precisar mais para frente entender a sintaxe do `data.celulas.forEach(function (celula) {});`, até aqui funcionou.
Eu tinha que ter escrito o que irei fazer com a tabela. Mas você acertou, vou criar outra função usando as informações de cada célula. Assim, preciso de um nome para cada célula conforme a posição da tabela.
Um detalhe, qualquer sugestão no título da dúvida fica bem vindo.

Comment: @Vasco juntei explicação sobre `data.celulas.forEach(function (celula) {});`. Fico contente de ter ajudado.